# Await code not being executes after await even if I resolve a promise on aggregation

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, async-await, es6-promise

I've been struggling promises for a while and I couldn't' find any solution to my problem yet.

**What I want to do;**

I'm fetching an aggregated data from MongoDB and assigning it's values to a class object.
Here's a piece of code of the aggregation;

```
 static get(email: BaseUser['email']) {
    const query = { email: email }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const data = this.model.aggregate([
            {
                $match: query
            }, {
                $project:
                {   // Get the last element of the array which is previous week's data
                    d1: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.myData1", -1] },
                    d2: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.myData2", -1] },
                    d3: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.myData3", -1] },
                    email: email
                }
            }
        ])
        resolve(data)
    })
}
```

and I'm calling above function in here;

```
  private static async set(email: string) {
    console.log(1)
    const data = await MongooseBusiness.get(email); // below code won't work
    console.log(data, 'data')
    const oldCumulativeCounts = data[0];
    console.log(4)
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve('a piece of data'));
}
```

Like I said in the above comment, the code that after the await is not working. Like it's not even there. Even if I resolve a promise in the `get` function. Any help?

Comment: Is `this.model.aggregate` an asynchronous function?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's mongoose's default aggregate function.

Comment: BTW, if I set a callback to `get`, also the callback is not being executed

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it, `this.model.aggregate()` is returning a Promise, which means that your method `get` is returning a `Promise<Promise<...>>`.

You could simply return `this.model.aggregate()` instead of `new Promise`:

```
 static get(email: BaseUser['email']) {
    const query = { email: email }
    return this.model.aggregate([
            {
                $match: query
            }, {
                $project:
                {   // Get the last element of the array which is previous week's data
                    d1: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.myData1", -1] },
                    d2: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.myData2", -1] },
                    d3: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.myData3", -1] },
                    email: email
                }
            }
        ])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work. Actually I already tried your answer at the first time then I saw a few answers on the SO and then I converted the `new Promise...` version.

Comment: Maybe you can try `this.model.aggregate(...).then(data => resolve(data))`. This will "un-wrap" the Promise again...